# ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy can invalidate session or just set expire field = true while sessision is exceed maximumSessions?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Hi I am using Spring security version 3.1.
I want to ask can we direct invalidate user session when sessions count exceeds limit from `maximumSessions` value field which is mentioned in `ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy`.
In my scenario, `maximumSessions` value is 1.
I restrict that only single user can have only single sessions. And if there exists another session for that user login then the old session will be destroyed from the session list. But right now the entry of that old session is visible in manager until I perform any action in old session.
Because of they just set expire field as true.

Answer (score 0):

According to the javadoc of [ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.6.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/session/ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy.html) the default behavior of the that strategy and I quote

> "The default behaviour is to expired the least recently used session"

That expiration logic will be performed by the [ConcurrentSessionFilter](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/session/ConcurrentSessionFilter.html)  upon subsequent requests with that session.

And furthermore if you set the `exceptionIfMaxExceeded` property in that strategy you can prevent new session being created at all.

Comment: but in that setuation just sessionInformation will have expire = true value.

Comment: but that session will show me on Tomcat Manager Application Session List. that i also want to delete. as of now that list show me session till i do not perform any action in that session.

Comment: Spring is really extendable. You can write your own ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy

Comment: can you please give me suggesion ? how should we make implementation if i want to perform this logic.